# Range filter and order by different field Firestore Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to order users by createtAt, but because I need to also query by age-range, first order by need to be on same field, but this ruins the whole concept.

Is it impossible to order by newest users when also using age range on different field or is there a work around this?

```
    database.collection("users")
        .whereField("birthday", isGreaterThan: exploreSettings.upperAgeDate)
        .whereField("birthday", isLessThan: exploreSettings.lowerAgeDate)
        .whereField("isHidden", isEqualTo: false)
        .order(by: "birthday")
        .order(by: "createdAt", descending: true)
        .limit(to: 8)
        .start(afterDocument: lastSnapshot)
        .getDocuments {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firestore queries can only order on a single field.

The only way to order over multiple values is find a way to combine the two values into a single field in a meaningful way. So: if you can find a way to express the relation between a birthday and a creation timestamp, you can combine those two values in a single field and order on that.

Note that this is hardly every feasible. The most common example I know of doing this are [Geohashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash), which combine a latitude and longitude in a way that allows querying for a geographical ranges.

Comment: Don't think this is possible in my case cause I too have to filter the users by geo range but haven't reach that part yet. First I need to find a way to filter the age and order by the createdAt timestamp. Also combining multiple values into one field seems messy, is this really recommended?

Comment: Filtering on one field and ordering on another is possible. But your code is trying to order on two fields, which isn't possible. Firestore queries can only order on a single field.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, been working on other stuff for a while, this is still a problem though. I don't need to orderBy birthday, that is just there because first order by most be on same field as the field I'm using range filter on. You did mention something about combining created at and birthday into the same field, how would this be possible?

Comment: I might have figured out a way to do this. When retrieving the data from Firestore it is by default ordered by the id, so if I can store the documents into Firestore with an id that makes the documents order by createdAt the then I don't need to order when retrieving the data. Please see my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50010771/order-by-document-id-firestore